# Copy Nodes and Children Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

This seems like a pretty basic XSLT question, but I have not been able to find the answer.

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="ProcessData/Document" >
    <xsl:element name="urn:create">
   <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ProcessData/Document" />
   </xsl:copy>
</urn:sObjects>
```

I would like to copy all nodes under ProcessData/Document. Currently, this only copies the values. I would like to copy all the elements under ProcessData/Document.

```
<ProcessData>
  <Document>
    <OTC_Alerts_KNA>
<Header><current_date_time_of_application_server>2015-03-31T21:56:51</current_date_time_of_application_server>
        <alert_type>EDI</alert_type>
        <single_character_indicator>O</single_character_indicator>
        <alert_functional_area>ORD</alert_functional_area>
        <customer_number>1000000131</customer_number>
        <customer_name>Dot Foods</customer_name>
        <sales_document_number>0000012062</sales_document_number>
        <sales_document_type>ZOR</sales_document_type>
    </Header>
    </OTC_Alerts_KNA>
  </Document>
</ProcessData>
```

I am trying to get this in the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:create
    xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <urn:sObjects
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c"/>
                <OTC_Alerts_KNA>
    <Header><current_date_time_of_application_server>2015-03-31T21:56:51</current_date_time_of_application_server>
            <alert_type>EDI</alert_type>
            <single_character_indicator>O</single_character_indicator>
            <alert_functional_area>ORD</alert_functional_area>
            <customer_number>1000000131</customer_number>
            <customer_name>Dot Foods</customer_name>
            <sales_document_number>0000012062</sales_document_number>
            <sales_document_type>ZOR</sales_document_type>
        </Header>
        </OTC_Alerts_KNA>
    </urn:create>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />` instead of `xsl:apply-templates`. Your context is already `ProcessData/Document`.

Comment: "*I would like to copy all nodes under ProcessData/Document.*" I am not sure you would like to do exactly that. Copying nodes copies them exactly as they are, including their namespace. If you want the "copied" nodes to inherit the namespace of their new parent element, you do **not** want to copy them (which *is* possible using the "deep copy" instruction of `xsl:copy-of`). Why don't you edit your question and post the result you are hoping to get in the end.

Comment: Made the edit thank you. I tried <xsl:copy-of select="node()" /> and it gave me everything under the /ProcessData element. I want only the items under the /ProcessData/Document element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that's the output you want, you can achieve it very easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <urn:create xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
        <urn:sObjects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/Document/*"/>
    </urn:create>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```