# XSLT - Extract some Elements with subnodes (.net XSLT 1.0)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have some trubles to extract only a few nodes from an XML-Document.
In my case i only get the "value" of my subnodes and not the node and its subnodes itself.
Im using .net 3.5 c# to Transform the document (XslCompiledTransform.Transform).

**Example XML (Source)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001"> 
    <Header>
        <PaketType>Household</PaketType>
        <ClientUid>6d513eae-b17f-4c30-b1eb-036ef36c5e8c</ClientUid>
        <ClientName>DEMO</ClientName>
        <UserLoginName>DEMO1</UserLoginName>
        <UserDisplayName>Demo1 User</UserDisplayName>
        <PointOfTime>2015-02-19T10:37:11.0768481+01:00</PointOfTime>
    </Header>
    <HeaderHousehold>
        <CustomerNumber>70716</CustomerNumber>
    </HeaderHousehold>
    <DataHouseHold>
        <Years>
            <YearData>
                <Year>2015</Year>
            </YearData>    
        </Years>
    </DataHouseHold>
    <DataDebts>
        <Years>
            <YearData>
                <Year>2015</Year>
            </YearData>
        </Years>
    </DataDebts>
</Response>
```

What i like to achieve is to select the "Repsonse/Header-Node" & its subnodes for the output (later some other nodes too) - But i want to keep the structure.

**My xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns="http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001"               
                    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name= "Response">
            <xsl:element name= "Header">
                <xsl:copy-of select = "/Response/Header/node()"/>        
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result i get:**
(I only get the "Header" node as a value...)

```
<Response>
    <Header>Household6d513eae-b17f-4c30-b1eb-036ef36c5e8cDEMORDEMO1Demo1 User2015-02-19T10:37:11.0768481+01:007071620152015</Header>
</Response>
```

**How the result should look like:**

```
<Response> 
    <Header>
        <PaketType>Household</PaketType>
        <ClientUid>6d513eae-b17f-4c30-b1eb-036ef36c5e8c</ClientUid>
        <ClientName>DEMO</ClientName>
        <UserLoginName>DEMO1</UserLoginName>
        <UserDisplayName>Demo1 User</UserDisplayName>
        <PointOfTime>2015-02-19T10:37:11.0768481+01:00</PointOfTime>
    </Header>
</Response>
```

I hope anybody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

snippet of my c# code:

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xml);
                XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();

                myXslTrans.Load(xslt);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists("result.xml"))
                    System.IO.File.Delete("result.xml");

                XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.xml", null);
                myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

                myWriter.Close();
```

Comment: **1.** The result that you show us is **not** the result received when applying your code. **2.** As i have explained to you in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499400/copy-nodes-and-children-using-xslt#comment47158108_29499400), you cannot copy elements without copying their namespace.

Comment: this question was not of mine - but thank you for pointing me to that article.. il take a look at it

Comment: Oops, sorry. about that.

Comment: @Cadburry In the stylesheet, it is no use to include `http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001` as a default namespace - this default would only apply to the elements in the XSLT document, not to the XPath expressions inside it. Declare this namespace with a _prefix_ - and prefix all elements from the input document that are mentioned in the XSLT stylesheet. (This still does not solve the problem of the input elements having namespaces, but it should clear up some confusion about _finding_ them.)

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thx - This helped me out - i changed the  declaration from: 
xmlns="http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001" to:  xmlns:xxx="http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001" and use xxx as prefix - now it works - thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The result that you show us is **not** the result received when applying your code.
2. You will get the result you're looking for, if you remove line #11:

   `<xsl:apply-templates/>`

While you're at it, you could simplify the whole thing to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">               
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Response">
    <Response>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>        
    </Response>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

***in response to your edited input, that puts the entire response in a namespace:***

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot copy elements without copying their namespace. If you want the output to be in no namespace, you need to create a new element for each "old" one. You also must use a prefix when addressing the elements in the source document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:k5="http://www.k-5.at/publicservices/download/MassenDatenResponseHaushalt:001"
exclude-result-prefixes="k5">               
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/k5:Response">
    <Response>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="k5:Header"/>        
    </Response>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>        
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Cadburry  it's still not the result one gets when running your code.

Comment: @Cadburry: No part of the code or source in your question would explain the presence of a node named `MassenDatenResponse`.

Comment: @Flynn1179 - now the result is correct (replaced the localized names) - I forot one main thing (sry) - a namespace...! (corrected also) - looks like this is the main problem without the ns the solution works... can you give me a hint?

Comment: iv used the solution in your edit - i dont want the namespaces in the output - thx